# Override VueJS Config File Parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, xampp, config

Sorry I'm new to Vue and learning more about it. Now I have an app running I get it ready and restructuring it. I've downloaded vue-devtools chrome extension to manage the config since I haven't found any config file and after reading on SOF that config isn't available by default.

1. I've created a file vue.config.js in the root of the app to manipulate certain parameters this didn't work

   module.exports = {
   allowHomepage: false,
   isSaaS: true,
   };
2. I have edited package.json and added the required parameteres, also didn't work

   {
   "private": true,
   "allowHomepage": false,
   "isSaaS": true,
   "scripts": {
3. Using vue-devtools chrome extension I configured the required parameters however it's a ready-only solution once the page reloaded everything is back to its default.

Also I have an issue when running the app using `php artisan serve` I get a 500 error as below

> main.js:11344 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/login 500 (Internal
> Server Error)

Any suggestion please?

Comment: There's no Vue config named `allowHomepage` or `isSaaS`. What are you trying to configure?

Comment: @tony19 that's true this is related to this app precisely however my concern how to override certain defined parameters in the app

Comment: How are these parameters defined in the app?